# How to set QPushButton stylesheet affecting buttons size?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qpushbutton, qtstylesheets

When I QApplication::setStyleSheet() with the following stylesheet

```
QPushButton {
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.3em 0.2em;
    border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,
                                  stop:0 #f4f4f4, stop:0.1 #8F8F8F, stop:1  #7B7B7B);
    color: white;
}
```

all buttons size is truncated to the size of the text. For example the OK buttons became squared. The effect is the same with any other stylesheet I tried on QPushButton. How to set buttons stylesheet without affecting their default size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can mess with the borders or padding without affecting the widget's default size. You can set [`min-width`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet-reference.html#min-width-prop) though.

From the docs: `If this property is not specified, the minimum width is derived based on the widget's contents and the style.`

```
QPushButton {
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.3em 0.2em;
    border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,
                                  stop:0 #f4f4f4, stop:0.1 #8F8F8F, stop:1  #7B7B7B);
    color: white;
    min-width: 70px;
}
```